# Salesforce web-to-lead not redirecting properly in Google Site

Tags: salesforce, sites

I've created a contact page in Google Sites. I'm using Salesforce web-to-lead to capture the info. Everything seems to be working except when I click Submit, it opens a new tab to my confirmation page. It creates the lead, but instead of redirecting the original page to the confirmation page, it opens up a new tab. This means the original tab is still there will the fields still filled. Below is the code.

This is the same outcome on all browsers and mac/pc machines.

I've put this code in a raw text file and opened it in a browser and it works perfectly. But the moment I add it into my Google Site in an HTML box, it does the above behavior.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Sati

```
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <META> element to your page <HEAD>.      -->
<!--  If necessary, please modify the charset parameter to specify the        -->
<!--  character set of your HTML page.                                        -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D50000000JOCj">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.eversauce.com">
<input type=hidden name="lead_source" value="web"/>

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--   <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                             --> 
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="sati@eversauce.com">      -->    
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<p><span style="font-size: small;"><b><label for="first_name">First Name</label></b></span>        <br/><input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" size="40" maxlength="40" /></p>
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><b><label for="last_name">Last Name</label></b></span><br /><input id="last_name" type="text" name="last_name" size="40" maxlength="80" /></p>
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><b><label for="email">Email</label></b></span><br /><input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="40" maxlength="80" /></p>
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><b><label for="phone">Phone</label></b></span><br /><input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" size="40" maxlength="40" /></p>
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><b><label for="company">Company</label></b></span><br /><input id="company" type="text" name="company" size="40" maxlength="40" /></p>
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><b><label for="description">Comment</label></b></span><br /><textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" /></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your form look like if you do a view source on the Google Site?

Since it works fine outside of Google Sites but opens a tab when used within it I'd be looking for modifications to the HTML made by Google. They may have directly altered the submit button or injecting javascript to alter the behaviour.

Also, be careful using the web-to-lead form without modification. You are opening yourself up to getting spammed with the unmodified form. See [Can web-to-lead be protected from spammers without additional server side processing?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23705/can-web-to-lead-be-protected-from-spammers-without-additional-server-side-proces)